# How do I add Previous/Next Post links for all POSTS in ONE category in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Go easy on me! I'm a noob and slow at modifying WP theme files. I have already created the child theme.

**How do I say in code "Display previous and next post links only for individual POSTS under the category "blog" ONLY?** So that every single posts marked "blog" will display previous and next post. This code from the codex looks like it applies to all categories. I just want it on ONE category.

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Previous in category', TRUE); ?>
```

[Source link: Codex Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link#Examples)

I've tried plugins, but there aren't any updated that won't crash the site.

Comment: Does your posts have multiple categories because that code should work

Comment: @PieterGoosen  Hello. No. How do I modify the code to say catid('blog') or ID# or something. When I add that code it puts previous and next link on ALL category posts.

Comment: That code should work then. The only way that it can fail is if you have multiple categories assigned to a post, **OR** if you are using a custom taxonomy and not the build in taxonomy `category`

Comment: @PieterGoosen Like I said, the code places previous/next links on ALL category posts. Without writing an ID or slug name, it won't specify which category posts. I was asking how do I exclude a category id and do I post this on the loop.php or category.php?

Comment: Crap, seems like I have misunderstood your question, sorry about that. Will post an answer now ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to display the next and previous post links on single posts which belongs to the `blog`  category, you first need to know if the specific post belongs to the `blog` category or not. This can be easily done with the [`has_category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) check.

Something like will work on your single post page

```
if ( has_category( 'blog' ) ) {
    // ADD YOUR NEXT AND PREVIOUS POST LINKS HERE
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! The template has a "page.php" "single.php" "loop.php" Which template file do I put your code on?

So change this default code?

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  
   get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
  
   endwhile;
   
  themezee_display_pagination();

  endif; ?>

Comment: That goes into single.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template for that category only. https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates - you can include whatever you want in the loop for that particular category.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful for putting a header on the top of the category main page. But how do I put previous and next post links for ALL Posts in the 'blog' category?

Comment: First: Did you set up your post limit in settings? "Blog pages show at most" settings under "Reading" . Do you have enough posts to exceed post amount to cause a "previous/next" links to show up?

Here is the Wordpress Codex on how to query for navigation links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link


The example given shows how its put into the the_loop() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering again! My limit is set to 10. I'm using a child theme so I don't have a front page or posts page setup.

Comment: you still can create your category-template file for this category (blog) or use the single.php file (but you would have to make sure that its only for that category) Category templates helps with that issue. this would go into your child-template directory. I've made cateogory templates for child-themes.